# Where to learn Trøndersk?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, norwegian, dialect

I am about to move to Trondheim, in Norway. The dialects of Norwegian seem to be quite different from each other, so, for the purpose of understanding speech, it seems relevant to get some exposure to the local dialect, Trøndersk (which is, more properly, a family of dialects, but presumably they tend to be somewhat close to one another).

Where can I find reasonably clear online material to listen to in some Trøndersk dialect, or even material for learning the dialect itself?

Comment: A YouTube search of "Trøndersk" yields many videos to watch. Some are pretty goofy and entertaining. This also looks pretty brilliant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=80&v=-3h_QMZgvlg

Comment: @AML Feel free to answer as a proper answer, if you can suggest particular videos which would be helpful.

Comment: "Tore på sporet" (series): https://tv.nrk.no/serie/tore-paa-sporet     The host is a Trønder.

Comment: Takk. Jeg har sia flytta til Horten, men andre kan fremdeles få nytte av din besvarelse, som ville vært mer synlig viss du skreiv den som en besvarelse, i stedet for en kommentar.